# Check if a list contains text at a particular line C#

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, contains

Below is the code I have, to add the first line of 5 text boxes to another list *(averageLetter1)*

I would like to create an IF statement to check if the lists contain text at a specific line and return true if so.

```
//average for letter 1 of each password
                averageLetter1.Add(pw.ElementAt(0));
                averageLetter1.Add(pw1.ElementAt(0));
                averageLetter1.Add(pw2.ElementAt(0));
                averageLetter1.Add(pw3.ElementAt(0));
                averageLetter1.Add(pw4.ElementAt(0));


                long AverageL1 = (averageLetter1.Sum()) / 5;
                MessageBox.Show(AverageL1.ToString());
```

I have tried using the *Contains* method, but cannot specify specific lines.

(Also I am fairly new to C# so I am still learning.)

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please include also the problem you are trying to solve, your question looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In other words, include an example what can be in the textboxes and what is the expected result.

Comment: Well...I have 5 text boxes (pw - pw4) and I wish to extract the first line of each and take an average of all of these, which have been added to the list "averageLetter1"

Basically I need an If statement, so that If a line exists perform this action on each text box, if not return false??

Comment: What do you mean by "average of the line"? Average length? Average of ASCII values of characters? Is it always integer and you need its average value?

Comment: Have you looked at the Lines property of TextBox? This should come handy for you!

Comment: yes the line is a long, its a stopwatch value in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if one of the entries in averageLetter1 contains some text, then you can use `averageLetter1[lineNumber].Contains(text)`. If you want to see if one of the entries is equal to some text, then you can use `averageLetter[lineNumber] == text`. If you want to find out if any of the lines equals some text and know the index, then you can use:

```
        var matches = averageLetter1.Where(x => x == text).Select((x, index) => index).ToList();

        if (matches.Count == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("No matches");
        else
        {
            // There may be more than one match, so iterate over the matches
            foreach (var matchIndex in matches)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("text matched at " + matchIndex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is NO such thing as MsgBox in C# or in the .NET Framework. you are probably referring to the classic VB of MsgBox (which is also strongly discouraged when using the .NET framework). you mean... MessageBox.Show(...)

Comment: You are quite correct.  I changed it to MessageBox.